# SELECT statement showing difference in between columns of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, case

I have 2 tables.
T_before and T_after, these two have the same table structure(datatypes, field name all the same).
T_before is the data right now in the moment.
T_after the the data that is used to check for differences.

I want to write a SELECT statement to extract which field is changed when comparing those two tables.

eg. For the same ID, T_before.name != T_after.name so in the 'changedField' column(which is created from the SELECT statement) is concatenated with string 'name'

Right now I wrote this.

```
SELECT CASE(WHEN T_before.name != T_after.name THEN 'name, ' ELSE '' END CASE) AS f1, 
       CASE(WHEN T_before.address != T_after.address THEN 'address, ' ELSE '' END CASE) AS f2, 
       CONCAT(f1,f2) AS changedField 
FROM T_before INNER JOIN T_after ON (T_before.id = T_after.id);
```

Now, I have about 150 fields to check. It is quite a lot field to create with this SELECT statement(Or is it not alot?). I there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
Result at the moment:

```
f1    |f2       |changedField
name, |address, |name, address,
```

The desired result:

```
changedField
name, address,
```

As mentioned, I have about 150 fields to check, so that is quite a number of field the sql statement I wrote will return

Comment: edit the question with some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I added desired result. What you mean by sample data? The CREATE TABLE statement with the INSERT INTO statement?

Comment: "Is there a better way to do this?" Yes, in the application layer. There are a lot of comparison algorithms out there pick one. You will just need the two recordsets to compare. If you still want to do it in sql use a procedure with dynamic query. Depending on your database which you didn't provide as a tag (you definitely should)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I added the tag. I am using mysql. At first, in the application layer, I loop through each of the 150 fields and compare one by one and it takes a long time to run those loop. That is why I am trying with sql. I will try to look at dynamic query.